# CUDA/C++ tab in project properties

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

1 - How to get the CUDA tab as in the figure

[image]

2 - When I add a .cu file to a project, then how to stop the Visual Studio in highlighting the CUDA keywords by red color as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to have CUDA set up properly with Visual Studio is to elect to install the Visual Studio integration when installing the CUDA toolkit. Then everything should be set up just fine.

You can however manually do the same by copying the rule and MS Build Extensions which come with your CUDA toolkit. You will find them (depending on your version) in

> %PATH_TO_NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Toolkit%\CUDA\<version>\extras\visual_studio_integration

There you will find the appropriate rules, build extensions, and registry information, including readme files on how to set things up.

But like I said, the easiest way it to select the integration when running the installer.

If you have set this up and you still don't have the relevant info appear, make sure that the Build Customizations are enabled. You can do so by going to  your project, right-clicking it and then go to `Build Customization`. There you can select the appropriate targets for your version of CUDA.

[image]